# Rails - ajax page partial update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my home.html.haml page rendering 3 partials:

```
%h1 Foo
#foo1
 = render partial: 'foo/foo', locals: {items: @foo1_items}
#foo2
 = render partial: 'foo/foo', locals: {items: @foo2_items}
#foo3
 = render partial: 'foo/foo', locals: {items: @foo3_items}
```

Currently, I have some remote links that refresh these parts individually firing an ajax call to to the home page:

```
= link_to 'refresh', home_path(mode: 'foo1'), remote:true
= link_to 'refresh', home_path(mode: 'foo2'), remote:true
= link_to 'refresh', home_path(mode: 'foo3'), remote:true
```

and I have a **home.js.erb** that contains something like this:

```
<% if params[:mode] == 'foo1'%>
$('#foo1').html('<%= j(render partial: 'foo/foo', locals: {items: @foo1_items}) %>')
<% elsif params[:mode] == 'foo2'%>
$('#foo2').html('<%= j(render partial: 'foo/foo', locals: {items: @foo2_items}) %>')
<% else %>
$('#foo3').html('<%= j(render partial: 'foo/foo', locals: {items: @foo3_items}) %>')
<% end %>
```

I am wondering:

1. if this is the default(suggested, best) Rails way to do a partial page refresh or generally the way to handle ajax requests?
2. if it would be faster to have server respond with pure html and let the client (javascript) to do the replacing?
3. how do you handle this in your application?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is the right way to do it in Rails
2. It will be the same thing as far as processing is concerned. Whatever is spitted out of server is executed on client browser and elements get updated. With server side you have more control with ERB.
3. The same way you have done it.

Hope this will help

Comment: It should be noted that this way is a bit wasteful of bandwidth, since there is a lot of redundancy in the data sent from the server (every update sends mostly the same markup with small changes). There are other ways of doing this by sending a smaller data representation to the client (e.g. JSON) and having the client interpret it and populate the markup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will wait in case anyone argues and then I'll mark your answer as the correct one ;)

Comment: i agree with @Slicedpan. you can definitely use some client side templating system like handlebars.